# Search for value based on column and row header

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a table of data, and want to retrieve the value specified for a specific row and column header. I've tried to use a nested HLOOKUP and VLOOKUP, but [the only examples I've found rely on a helper column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7Vtu.png) that introduce new challenges.

I have a feeling this is possible using INDEX(MATCH), but can't quite seem to work it out.

I have a screenshot of what I'm looking for.

Update: I'm looking for a formula that will work as I had more Beers across the columns (it could be 2, it could be 100). And also needs to work where I would add more rows of ingredients.

[image]

Comment: INDEX/MATCH/MATCH?

Comment: Or, Double `XLOOKUP()` in O365, lot of queries on this in SO, have you tried searching them ?

Comment: ... noting that XLOOKUP doesn't exist in Google Sheets yet - best to only use appropriate tags if you want a solution for a specific platform. Microsoft Excel is not Google Sheets.

Comment: `=INDEX(B2:C4,MATCH(A10,A2:A4,0),MATCH(B9,B1:C1,0))`

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(B2:C4*(A2:A4=A10)*(B1:C1=B9))` would work in both GS and Excel. Both apps have their own unique functions that could make it work. As @BigBen mentioned, choose one and stick with it.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=VLOOKUP(A10; A2:C9; MATCH(B9; 1:1; 0); 0)
```

Comment: I understand this answers this particular situation, but the challenge is I might end up having 10,15,100 different beers... I need to update this in the original description. Sorry about not specifying that.

Answer (score 0):

This is overkill for your example, but would be what I'd consider my own "best practice" for heavier Excel lookups.

First off, I'd recommend [using the table feature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c#:%7E:text=To%20quickly%20create%20a%20table,row%2C%20and%20then%20click%20OK.), defining the range of A1:C4 in your example and making sure to confirm first row as headers.

Once you have that in place, in place you can run a lookup easily using header names. [XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929) is by far the easiest if you have a version of Office365 or Excel 2021.

Note: Column1 is the default filler name when a table is missing a header value

XLOOKUP solution from your example:
`=XLOOKUP(A10,Table1[Column1],Table1[Beer '#2],"")`

If you're going to be filling in a bunch of combinations, rearranging the order from the original format, or just looking up based on conditions that may not be consistently in the same place - Tables will be a huge help, with XLOOKUP making the whole process human readable.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using both the `index` and `match` functions within Google Sheets.

Using the example below as the data where the date field is variable as well as the billing_team:

[image]

If I want to get the value for `team2` on `2023-12-31` I would use the functions:

```py
=index(
 data!A1:C4,
 match("team2",data!A1:A,0),
 match(DATEVALUE("2023-12-31"),data!A1:1)
)

Returns: 3,582.22
```

| function | explained | value returned |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `data!A1:C4` | The range of data to search including headings | 3,582.22 |
| `match("",data!A1:A,0)` | Returns the row that `team2` was found | 2 |
| `match(DATEVALUE("2023-12-31"),data!A1:1)` | Returns the column where the date `2023-12-31` is found. **DATEVALUE()** is not required if just matching a non-date string | 2 |

eg. The query is parsed as:

```py
=index( data!A1:C4, 2, 2 )

Returns the 2nd Row and Column of the Values within A1:C4 of the sheet `data`
```